# Can another thread enter a monitor, while the waiting one is notified?

Tags: java, concurrency

I am investigating Java concurrency and I've found one interesting question which I cannot answer.

For example, I have three threads: ThreadA, ThreadB and ThreadC. ThreadA enters the monitor, and invokes method wait(). Then ThreadB enters the same monitor, invokes method notify() and continue owning the monitor during some period of time. While ThreadB is owning the monitor, ThreadC tries to acquire the monitor too. My question is whether ThreadC can acquire the monitor earlier then ThreadA when ThreadB release it or not? If it can, why? Which conditions should be followed to reproduce it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the Javadoc on Object.notify():

> The awakened thread will compete in the usual manner with any other threads that might be actively competing to synchronize on this object; for example, the awakened thread enjoys no reliable privilege or disadvantage in being the next thread to lock this object.

So there exists the possibility that ThreadC owns the monitor before ThreadA. There is no defined order in which any of the threads enter/obtain the monitor, nor is there any priority or fairness mechanism in place for standard synchronization. All it really guarantees is that for a given lock object, only on thread will be in the synchronized block at once.

Given this fact, careful design considerations should go into how threads obtain the lock and for how long. A thread that repeatedly attempts to acquire a lock (acquire and then release but then acquire again) can cause another thread to be locked out indefinitely (called thread starvation).

Using `ReentrantLock` with a fairness policy can partially overcome this issue at some performance cost (its slightly slower than traditional synchronization).